# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - using UITableView

Tags: swift

I am using UITableView inside a View Controller.

In viewDidLoad i have this:

```
var PlayersUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if (PlayersUserDefault.arrayForKey("playersKey") != nil){
            players = PlayersUserDefault.arrayForKey("playersKey")
        }
```

and this code gives me error:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return players!.count
}
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I don´t understand this, can someone help me. Sorry, my English is not that good.

Comment: try to print `players!.count` I guess it's returning `nil`

Comment: @Aladin - Yes it does. What should i do? The error appear when I try to open the view controller that contains the UITableView.

Comment: can you share the declaration of `players`

Comment: @Aladin - var players = NSUserDefaults().arrayForKey("playersKey")

Comment: @Aladin new question can you take a look please?

Comment: You should've created a new post with the new question! Now all the comments that were added because of your earlier question doesn't make sense.

Comment: You shouldn't edit questions like that. If you have a new question, simply click the New Question button. Now the answer here makes no sense, and the question is not related to the original issue at all.

Comment: I have restored the question to the original content. From now on, please ask new questions using the Ask Question button. I saved the contents of your new question here, so you can just copy and paste it when asking a new question: http://pastebin.com/zGT8AqjE

Comment: @ThomasQuack Please do not replace the content of the question. Instead, *ask a new question*. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `NSUserDefaults` returns nil if the key does not contain a value. `NSUserDefaults` method like `objectForKey` and `arrayForKey` return optionals.

If the key doesn't exist, they return nil.

Try this instead:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
  numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return players?.count ?? 0
}
```

That uses the "nil coalescing operator" which returns the value if it's not nil, or the value after the ?? if it is nil.

Comment: Thanks, worked! Can you also check my new question on top?

Comment: Don't edit your original question to ask a new question. Ask a new question! This site is used by lots of people who find answers to past questions helpful. By editing your original question you destroy that history. Also, if my answer meets your needs, accept it. (Click the checkmark.)